# Неправильное отображение выбора даты на странице

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo

В первом случае **input** является пикером даты.

Во втором случае по какой то причине он превращается в обычный текстбокс.
Оба поля в Delivery являются **DateTime?**, но при подстановке **Delivery.ExpectedDeliveryDate** в **name** первой строки все работает.

Используется KendoUI, формат файла .cshtml

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Delivery.PlanCustomerArrivalDate" value="..." />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Delivery.ExpectedDeliveryDate" value="..." />
```

Comment: А оба свойства - DateTime?

Comment: @Aarnihauta ага

Comment: [Тут](https://www.telerik.com/forums/template-multiple-date-pickers) решением оказалось обернуть их в div.

Comment: Обернуты оба в <div class="col-sm-8">

Comment: Кстати, `asp` - жутко старая технология, в которой писали на языках JScript, VBScript. Вы используете `asp.net`. Ставьте метки правильно.

Comment: Проблема решается добавлением в файл js в функцию загрузки страницы следующей строки: ```$('input[name="Delivery.PlanCustomerArrivalDate"]').kendoDatePicker({ format: "dd.MM.yyyy" });```

Comment: @bubadev лучше ответ запостите

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается добавлением в файл js в функцию загрузки страницы следующей строки: `$('input[name="Delivery.PlanCustomerArrivalDate"]').kendoDatePicker({ format: "dd.MM.yyyy" });`